# Remove book from search results if it has already been purchased

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to check the books_ordered table to get a list of book ISBN's that have been ordered. If an ISBN exists in teh books_ordered table I do not want it to show in the list of search results. I have the following code:

```
include "include.php";
session_start();

$query1 = 'SELECT isbn as myisbn FROM books_ordered';
$result1 = mysqli_query($con, $query1) or die("Error in query $query1: " . mysqli_error());
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){
$isbn=$row['myisbn'];
}

$query = 'SELECT * FROM book';
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die("Error in query $query: " . mysqli_error());

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
if($isbn!=$row[0]){
echo $row[1]."<br>";
}
}
mysqli_close($con);             //closes the connection

?>
```

The script I have only hides the first isbn from the books_ordered table in the search results, does anyone have any ideas why? I'm guessing it's something to do with the brackets in the while loops, i just can't figure it out. Or if anyone knows a better way of doing this it would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only storing the last value in $isbn since it is not an array.
You need to add the isbn into an array, and then check each row in the second query against that array.

But I would probably do the processing in the SQL statement instead. Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM book where isbn not in (select isbn from books_ordered)
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be more efficient to filter out the unwanted results from the book table in a single query, like so:

```
select b.* from book b
left join books_ordered o on b.isbn = o.isbn
where o.isbn is null
```

Comment: Thank's for taking the time to respond, I didn't try your answer as I just used the simpliest method mentioned, but perhaps it will help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

What is your database structure for "book"? You can easily make a "JOIN"-Command.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood well, you want to show only the books are not ordered yet.

You could use this SQL sentence:

```
SELECT * FROM book WHERE isbn_row NOT IN (SELECT isbn FROM books_ordered)
```

First we select the isbn of the ordered books with: `SELECT isbn FROM books_ordered`
When we have the list, using the clause NOT IN we can select from BOOK all books except all that we get the isbn in the first sentence.

I hope is useful for you.

Comment: Thank-you very much for taking the time to respond, your answer is the same as above and worked perfectly.